# How can I use Espresso for testing on Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-espresso

I do not understand. How can I add and use Espresso in my project?

Espresso url: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/

How to connect this library to my project? I would like to have an example in Eclipse.

Comment: Here's a blog post I wrote on how to integrate Espresso in an Android project: https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/an-introduction-to-espresso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Espresso jar file https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/#git%2Fbin%2Fespresso-dependencies . I added jar file to my project and it's very easily =).

Comment: yeah sorry. See my comment. I was thinking about a different library.

Answer (score 2):

To use Espresso for Android you have to create test project which will test your main application under test. This [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso#Espresso_Setup_Instructions) contains Espresso setup instruction for Eclipse and Android Studio. And also some basic steps you have to do (with test project but not with the main app) before running your tests: adding GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner into AndroidManifest.xml file and changing Run Configurations. After you finish - take a look on examples from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoStartGuide).